# ¿Cómo aplicar más de una validación personalizada a un campo con mongoose?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy aprendiendo validaciones en `mongoose`, pero no logro aplicar varias validaciones personalizadas a un mismo campo.

Basándome en:

```
    var Esquema = new mongoose.Schema({
        campo1 : {type: String, validate: [
            function (campo1) {
                //..lo que se necesite validar
            },
            'Mensaje error de validacion'}
    });
```

Lo anterior funciona a la perfección, pero ¿Cómo se podría hacer si requiero aplicar mas de 1 validación personalizada a `campo1`?

Hasta ahora lo que he intentado es:

```
    var Esquema = new mongoose.Schema({
        campo1 : {type: String, validate: [
            function (campo1) {
                //..lo que se necesite validar 1
            },
            'Mensaje error de validacion 1'},
            function (campo1) {
                //..lo que se necesite validar 2
            },
            'Mensaje error de validacion 2'}
    });
```

Este intento sólo toma la primera validación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
var variasValidaciones = [
    { validator: validacion1, msg: 'No cumple validacion1' },
    { validator: validacion2, msg: 'No cumple validacion2' }
];

var validacion1 = function(string) {
   // Codigo de validacion1
};

var validacion2 = function(string) {
   // Codigo de validacion2
};

var Esquema = new mongoose.Schema({
        campo1 : {type: String, validate: variasValidaciones}
...
```

Comment: NetVicious, gracias por compartir, funciono sin problemas.